# How to focus on <p> in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

I'm using contenteditable div to make rich editor.
My problem now is I can't get caret to be positioned on `<p>` right after I embed Instagram frame.
What I tried is create new `<p>` and focus on it after I embed Instagram frame. But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know solution of this problem?

[I make JSFiddle as example](https://jsfiddle.net/hiro14/mhak78e8/4/)
(I put one of embed code in CSS block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the contenteditable [spec](https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditable.html#dfn-legal-caret-positions) states that it should be possible to place the cursor inside an empty p tag like this:

```
<div>aaa<p>|</p>bbb</div>
```

[Webkit](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456917&thanks=456917&ts=1423511681) (Safari) and [Blink](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15256) (Chrome) currently do not support it. More info [here](https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/70).

Fortunately, there is a relatively easy workaround. We just need to get some content inside the p tag, allowing us to place the cursor here. One option could be to append a textnode that contains a [Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). This approach is sometimes useful for situations involving inline tags.

In your case, the most effective solution would be to simply append a line break to the paragraph. Contenteditable implementations typically treat line breaks inside block tags as a "temporary holding nodes", and the default handling is the same across major browsers. The initial result should look like this:

```
<div>aaa<p>|<br></p>bbb</div>
```

And as soon as you start typing, the BR will be replaced (the browser does this automatically):

```
<div>aaa<p>inner text|</p>bbb</div>
```

Even when you delete the inner text, the browser should automatically re-insert a line break, so you will always be able to get the cursor back inside.

I've forked and updated your jsfiddle with an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/az4rjjsh/).

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is useful for me!! I put this off till later.